# iOS: How to excecute the command `openssl s_client -connect <server>:443 </dev/nullsl x509 -outform DER -out <name.der>` with OpenSSL under Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, openssl, x509certificate

I did a protection for my Web Service calls with [Man-in-the-Middle Attacks in iOS with SSL Pinning tuto](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1484288-preventing-man-in-the-middle-attacks-in-ios-with-ssl-pinning)
I would like to renew my certificate on the iOS each two month because this the time my server has to renew his certificate.

For now I do it manually by taping on my mac command line:

```
openssl s_client -connect <server>:443 </dev/nullsl x509 -outform DER -out <name.der> with OpenSSL under Swift ?
```

The problem is that I have to send to my customer a new app for install, with a new certificate in the bundle each month.
For this, I would like to use the [OpenSSL GitHub for iOS](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/OpenSSL) to generate it locally on the ipad/iphone.
I cannot find the way to use it, do you know what is the code I must write to execute that command in Swift by using this github?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have u seen https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/OpenSSL

Comment: @dengApro yep, but impossible to find the way to tap the command I put in my ticket